# Compare using curdate while ignoring Year? - mysqli , PHP?

Tags: php, date, mysqli

I am trying to check for Birthdays from data in the table using CURDATE() function. Sadly My code currently only outputs names if the birthDate is the current date! (i.e inluding year). I am trying to figure out how to **ignore Year** here and **only compare month and day.**

Please assume this is the table

```
| book_no |   name    | dob        | mobile_no  |
|---------|-----------|------------|------------|
|    1    | ABCD      | 1995-08-01 | 123456789  |
|    2    | EFGH      | 2016-08-01 | 123456789  | 
|    3    | HIKJ      | 2016-05-01 | 123456789  |
|    4    | LMNO      | 2016-08-01 | 123456789  |
|    5    | PQRS      | 1995-08-01 | 123456789  |
```

This is the code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "gold";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

}
$sql1 = "SHOW TABLES";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
if(!$result1)
{
        echo "Error fetching data from tempTable: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
else 
{
        while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc())
        {
            foreach($row1 as $key1 => $var1)
            {
                $sql2 = "SELECT name,mobile_no  FROM " .$var1. " WHERE dob = CURDATE()";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
                $bBoy = array();
                    if(!$result2)
                    {
                            echo "Error fetching data from tempTable: " . mysqli_error($conn);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc())
                            {
                                echo $row2['name']."<br>";
                                echo $row2['mobile_no']."<br>";
                            }
                    }   

            }
        }   
}

>?
```

This code only outputs

```
EFGH
123456789  
LMNO
123456789
```

while it should have been all except book_no -3.
*Please Help*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MONTH and DAY functions provided in MySQL to compare just those parts of the date to the date you have stored in the table.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT name,mobile_no  FROM " .$var1. " WHERE MONTH(dob) = " . date('m') . " AND DAY(dob) = " . date('d');
```

Comment: You missed to close the quote at the end but the query still throws this error `Error fetching data from tempTable: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'd')' at line 1Error fetching data from tempTable: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'D')' at line 1`

Comment: I just had a single quote instead of a double quote. I have corrected it in my answer.

Comment: `Error fetching data from tempTable: Unknown column 'Aug' in 'where clause'` this is the error now. You are close!

Comment: Me bad, little m for numerical month not capital M ... answer corrected (again!).